# Python Dict From List With Keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list

`[('us-west-2', 'vol-XXXXXXXX'), ('us-west-2', 'vol-YYYYYYYY'), ('us-west-2', 'vol-ZZZZZZZZ')]`

That I want to turn to a dict that looks like

`[{region:'us-west-2', name:'vol-XXXXXXXX'},{region:'us-west-2', name:'vol-YYYYYYYY'},{region:'us-west-2', name:'vol-ZZZZZZZZ'}]`

Comment: SO isn't a coding service. What have you tried so far?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request to show you teh codez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension to do it.

```
region_list = [
    ('us-west-2', 'vol-XXXXXXXX'), 
    ('us-west-2', 'vol-YYYYYYYY'), 
    ('us-west-2', 'vol-ZZZZZZZZ')
]

print [{"region": region, "name": name} 
       for region, name in region_list]
```

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work:

```
>>> l = [('us-west-2', 'vol-XXXXXXXX'), ('us-west-2', 'vol-YYYYYYYY'), ('us-west-2', 'vol-ZZZZZZZZ')]
>>> new_list = [{'region':i[0], 'name':i[1]} for i in l]
```

Comment: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: it was a typo, I fixed it, try now. (it works for me)